# Wordpress menu links wrong

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress theme which has been designed, however, the links are wrong at the top

**For example:**

About Us should go to [here](http://www.luof.co.uk/aboutus.html)

Furniture should go to [here](http://store.luof.co.uk)

The link to the blog is [here](http://www.luof.co.uk/blog)

I have already tried adjusting the position, and the width of each menu item, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress Admin console there is the option Appearance>Menu. Create a new menu, add the items you want (you can add pages you made, create custom items with links to other pages, etc), save the menu. Now go to Appeareance>Themes>Customize current theme and change the navigation path.

Comment: Lovely thanks! still learning Wordpress,forgot that you had to make the menu in the Wordpress software, not in the code! Thanks alot! :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you have more issues I can always help!